# Curves that share a tangent

Tags: calculus

Find the comment tangents to: $$ y = x^2 + 1 $$ $$y=-2x^2-3$$

I believe if they share mutual tangents, then their slopes should be identical. As such: $$2x = -4x$$

And there exists a point $(a,b)$ on the curve $x^2+1$ and $(c,d)$ on $-2x^2-3$.

Using this information, I used the slope formula as so:
$$\frac{d-b}{c-a} = f'(a)$$

To get:
$$2a(c-a) = d-b$$ or 
$$2a(c-a) = f(a) - g(c)$$

Since $2a$ = $-2c+2$, I got $$a=-c+1$$ 
From here, I can substitute a in to the equation above and hopefully solve for $c$.

Am I on the right path? I believe my solution is becoming too complicated.

Comment: What does it mean ? You have asked the **same question 5 days ago** (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1987845)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct. With a bit different notation we have:
$$
f(x)=x^2+1 \qquad g(x)=-2x^2-3
$$

As you noted a common tangent is a line that passes thorough the points:

$$
(x_1,f(x_1)) \qquad (x_2,g(x_2))
$$ 
such  that
$$
\frac{g(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=f'(x_1)=g'(x_2)
$$
Substituting from 
$$
f'(x_1)=g'(x_2) \quad \rightarrow \quad  2x_1=-4x_2 \quad \rightarrow \quad x_1=-2x_2
$$
we have:
$$
g(x_2)=-2x_2^2-3 \qquad f(x_1)=x_1^2+1=4x_2^2+1
$$
So the equation:
$$
\frac{g(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=g'(x_2)
$$
becomes
$$
\frac{-2x_2^2-4x_2^2-4}{x_2-2x_2}=-4x_2 \quad \iff \quad -6x_2^2-4=-12x_2^2
$$
that gives
$$
x_2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \qquad \mbox{and} \qquad x_1=\mp2\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
$$

and from this you can find the points of tangency and the equation of the two tangent lines.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the notation here. So since $x_1=−2x_2$ , $f(x_1)$ = $-2(x_2)$ Correct? I got $$\frac{-2(x_2) + 4(x_2)}{(x_2) - 2(x_2)} $$

Comment: Iìve added something and corrected  a typo. I hpe it's more clear now.

Comment: Noticed my mistake again. THanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Any tangent to the first curve at the point $(a, f(a))$ is given by:
$$y = 2ax - a^2 + 1$$
Any tangent to the second curve at the point $(b, f(b))$ is given by:
$$y =-4bx + 2b^2 - 3$$
Both tangents need to be the exact same. Slopes and y-intercepts need to match. As such, we get a system:
$$2a = -4b, -a^2 + 1 = 2b^2 - 3$$
Solving this simultaneously gives:
$$(a, b) = \left ( 2\sqrt{\frac23}, -\sqrt{\frac23} \right ) or
\left ( -2\sqrt{\frac23}, \sqrt{\frac23} \right )$$
Giving two common tangents:
$$y = 4\sqrt{\frac23}x - \frac53,y = -4\sqrt{\frac23}x - \frac53$$

Comment: For your tangent equations, why is it that $y=2ax-a^2+1$ is the equation? I'm assuming this is in the form of $y=mx+b$ where $m=2a$ and $b=a^2+1$? Correct me if i'm wrong, but shouldn't it be $y=2ax+a^2+1$

Comment: For the first one, the tangent is:
$$y = 2a(x - a) + a^2 + 1$$
Simplifying that gives what I have above.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure. But I noticed the same consistency in your second equation, I figured $y=-4bx-2b^2-3$ would be the equation however you got $y=-4bx+2b^2-3$

Comment: Yeah, I forgot my own process here. Everything above is as expected. The tangent lines don't always look like their original equations, this was just a coincidence.